# How to add AdMob ads on Phonegap Android App?

Tags: android, cordova, admob

How to add AdMob ads on Phonegap Android App?

I'm use Adobe PhoneGap Build https://build.phonegap.com/apps

I don't know how to use AdMob Plugin.

Comment: I think this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25224589/how-to-add-admob-ads-on-phonegap-android-app) is what you are finding.